# C++, attach to process, breakpoint won't be hit

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a big application and I want to debug a given class. So I compile the DLL the class is in, in release and replace, in the application setup directory, the DLL and also add its PDB. I cannot do it in Debug since the application then does not work properly.

After doing that, I start the application and attach to it with the VS debugger. But my four breakpoints in the four methods I wish to debug exhibit the message "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

In an unsuccessful attempt to fix this, I have added the pdb I have copied to the installation directory of my application to the pdb locations in Debug | Options and Settings | Debugging | Symbols.

Why is this happening, can something be done?

Comment: you need to compile in debug mode. In release mode, due to optimizations, the compiled code will be very different than the source code, so many times a line in source code does not have an equivalent line in compiled code. Same for variables.

Comment: Unfortunately with the above setup if I replace the dll with its debug version, the application won't work properly.

Comment: try release mode with optimizations turned off

Comment: and what do you mean by "won't work"

Comment: Those pdb files should be exactly the same pdb files that were generated when you compiled the current executables. If it was generated earlier/later than symbols won't match

Comment: by won't work I mean: the application has a bunch of subapplications that can be started, when I start the subapplication that will load the DLL of interest, a message is shown saying it cannot be started, when I use the debug DLL. When I use the release version, it starts correctly.

Comment: Release mode with optimizations turned off does not make a difference. I think the problem is it does not load the PDB file.

Comment: The whole application was compiled a few weeks ago. You mean (Asesh) it is not possible to compile a DLL and replace it in the application setup directory and add the PDB?

Comment: When you a compile an application, it's going to generate corresponding pdb files right? Now if you move that app some where else and then compile that app again but use newer pdb files then debugger will reject that pdb file. So in other words, you must use the same pdb files that were generated when you compiled that DLL

Comment: The application has an EXE file and hundreds of DLLs, so I cannot replace one DLL and add its PDB and hope I can debug a class in that DLL? If the answer is no, you can explain this as answer.

Comment: Like I said if it's not the exact PDB file of the compiled binaries then debugger will reject it. If you are debugging the class of that DLL, build that DLL again and debug it

Comment: You can compile a release build and generate PDB files for this release build. In your project settings, go to  Linker > Debugging, check "Generate Debug Info".

Comment: As a fallback solution I suggest inserting debug output (via message boxes (GUI), command line, log file - preferring the most simple one) into the class you want to debug.